# How do I merge two nodes for a Binary Tree in C++?

Tags: c++

```
Node BinaryTree::Merge(Node* n1, Node* n2)
{
     Node sum = n1+n2;
     return sum;
}
```

This returns an error: "IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to a very specific case of a very general (and fairly obvious) error. It is unlikely to be of use to future readers.

Comment: Obviously, you can't add two pointers. Without knowing what a node is or what it means to merge them, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int BinaryTree::Merge(Node* n1, Node* n2)
{
    int sum = n1->nodeValue+n2->nodeValue;
    return sum;
}
```

Couldn't add two pointers which was quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to declare the 'Node' you want to return on the heap rather than the runtime stack. try

```
Node* BinaryTree::Merge(Node* n1, Node* n2)
{
     Node* sum = new Node(n1+n2);
     return sum;
}
```

You may need to refactor your code a bit for this. Make sure that you are deallocating n1 and n2 and the returned Node to avoid memory leaks.